# Parsing a time stamp in a string using the ICU library, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, parsing, time, icu

I'm trying to use the ICU library to convert a time stamp from a string to a time_t value.

To do so, I though all I had to do is create a time instance and call its `parse()` function. Unfortunately, all I get is a U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR from the parser.

There is a simplified version of the code that shows the unexpected behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unicode/datefmt.h>
#include <unicode/errorcode.h>
#include <unicode/locid.h>
#include <unicode/smpdtfmt.h>
#include <unicode/timezone.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LocalPointer<DateFormat> dt(DateFormat::createTimeInstance());

    UErrorCode err(U_ZERO_ERROR);
    UDate const result(dt->parse("12:05:33", err));

    std::cerr << "*** err = " << u_errorName(err)
              << " and result = " << result << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the output is

```
*** err = U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR and result = 0
```

I was expecting something more like a representation of the time such as 12 x 3600 + 5 * 60 + 33 = 43533.

Am I doing something wrong? From the [documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime), it looks like the library is capable of converting various types of time stamps.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the format of your time string does not match the default style/locale of the `DateFormat` object that `createTimeInstance()` returns.  Use the `style` and `aLocale` parameters of `createTimeInstance()` to specify the particular style/locale that `parse()` should expect.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that with "en_US". The default locale is "English". I really don't see why the time I have would fail in English. I also tried with other times like "05:33" and "11:20 AM".

Comment: I also have a timezone setup like this: `LocalPointer<TimeZone> tz(TimeZone::createTimeZone("Pacific Time"));` and `dt->setTimeZone(*tz);`. It doesn't help either.

Comment: You are focusing on the `locale` and ignoring the `style`.  The default `style` for `createTimeInstance()` is `kDefault`, which is an alias for `kMedium`.  Try specifying `kShort` instead: `DateFormat::createTimeInstance(kShort, Locale::getUS())`

Comment: I tried them all, short, full, medium... Plus it feels like these represent the length of the date rather than the time. Not too sure though.